# Set up Shutter (or other screengrab tool) to capture a preset area from a keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, screenshot

I have Shutter installed which i use for screengrabbing.  It always asks me to draw my selection area on screen, but for an upcoming job i'm going to be going to lots of different urls on our website and capturing the exact same area every time:  for the sake of argument, let's say that the upper left corner is [0,120] and the bottom right corner is [800,720].

It would make my life so much easier if i could set up a keyboard shortcut to capture that area and just ask me for the filename.  Is this possible?

if it's not possible with Shutter, is it possible with a different desktop screengrabbing tool?

thanks, Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Shutter

When calling [**Shutter**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/shutter) from the command line we can give it option `--select` to grab a defined region of our screen with:

```
shutter --select=x,y,width,height
```

Below command will save the screen from coordinates 0,120 with image dimensions 800x600 to the file `screenhot.png` in the directory we are in.

```
shutter --select=0,120,800,600 -e --output="screenshot.png"
```

For convenience we can add this command to a keyboard shortcut.

---

#### ImageMagick Import

Another very versatile application to obtain custom screenshots would be [**import**](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/import.php) of [**ImageMagick**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=imagemagick) [image: Install imagemagick].

```
import -window <id|name> [-crop <geometry>] filename.png
```

We can import either from the whole desktop (`-window root`) or from a window defined by ID or name (run `xwininfo` to get the window ID on mouse click). The `<geometry>` value defines the screen region with the following syntax: `<xsize>x<ysize>+<xoffset>+<yoffset>`. Below command will save a 800x600 pixel sized screenshot with offset x=0,y=120 off the left upper corner:

```
import -window root -crop 800x600+0+120 testshot.png
```

Comment: Thanks @Takkat - i'm, getting these errors: `WARNING: gnome-web-photo is missing --> screenshots of websites will be disabled!, 
WARNING: Net::DBus::GLib is missing --> Ubuntu One support will be disabled!
WARNING: Image::ExifTool is missing --> Writing Exif information will be disabled!
INFO: There is already another instance of Shutter running!`.  it would be annoying if i have to close the regular desktop shutter before doing this.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: see edit for an alternative.